# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, enterprise-library

I am trying use EnterpriseLibrary Version=5.0.414.0,in my WCF service.But it throwing run time error while executing Logger.Write(log) method.Error Detailed is

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=5.0.414.0

Anyone have idea?

Comment: Yes.  The application was built to make use of the Microsoft Enterprise Library version 5.0.  Normally, this should be installed by the installation that installed the dependent software.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The application was built to make use of the Microsoft Enterprise Library version 5.0. Normally, this should be installed by the installation that installed the dependent software.

You can manually download and install Microsoft Enterprise Library at this link: [Download Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15104).

Once that is done, your software should function nominally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I m trying as above.The functionality is working fine for a console application bt started throwing exception once it is used in WCF.Any difference?

Comment: Check the directory contents of your console app and see if the enterprise library assemblies are located within.  Assemblies will be loaded either from the directory of the executing process or the GAC (Global Assembly Cache).  One way to resolved this would be to use `GACUTIL.EXE` to install enterprise library into the GAC if it isn't already.